# How to delete children of a tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, theory, prefix-tree

I need to delete all children of my prefix tree except the root. I'm not asking any code. I just need a method to traverse and delete all children of a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use post order traversal to traverse the tree and delete the nodes as:

```
function deleteTree(node, tree_root) {
     if (node != null) {
         // recursively delete left sub-tree.
         deleteTree(node->left, tree_root);

         // recursively delete right sub-tree.
         deleteTree(node->right, tree_root);

         // time to delete the node..but only if it's not root.
         if( node != tree_root) {
              delete node;
         }  
     }
}
```

and call the above function as:

```
deleteTree(root,root);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method `delete`, which takes a tree node:

```
 for each child in node
   call delete on child
   remove child from node
   free child
```

For each child of root call this delete method.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, by you may do some elegant - tree may not be used after deletion, so you may write a destructor of a node:

```
struct Node // Non-copyable!
{
  Node *left, *right;

  Node()
    : left(NULL)
    , right(NULL)
  {
  }
  ~Node()
  {
    delete left;
    delete right;
  }
};
```

And that's all! You use it: `delete root`. Note that you may not test for NULL before `delete` because it works well (just return) by C++ standard.

Comment: I need to use root after deletion.

Comment: Ok, method is good for this: `void DeleteChildren() { delete left; delete right; }` :) Unlike method above, you should test for `node != NULL`